# Replacing sub array in Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to replace a sub array in a Numpy array, with an array of the same shape, such that any changes are mirrored in both arrays. I've run the following code in IDLE.

```
import numpy
a=numpy.zeros((2,1))

a
array([[0.],
       [0.]])

b=numpy.zeros((1))
b
array([0.])

a[0]=b
b[0]=1

b
array([1.])
```

Now what I'd want the output of `a` to be in this example is:

```
array([[1.],
       [0.]])
```

but instead I get:

```
a
array([[0.],
       [0.]])
```

I've been trying to read up on slicing and indexing, but it's not immediately obvious to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if it's even possible to get the result I want. So I was hoping someone could tell me how, if at all, I can do this.

Comment: `a[0]=b` assigns the value of `b` to `a`, but not the object.  If `a` was a list it would work, but not with numeric arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize `b` as being a slice of `a`, then changing `b` will modify `a` aswell, namely:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.zeros((2,1))
b=a[0]
b[0]=1

a
array([[1.],
       [0.]])
```

Hope this helps.